# Is It Make Sense to Combining Feature Ranking Methods by Averaging The Ranking Results?

Tags: feature-selection, ranking

I have two separate filter-based feature ranking methods, i.e., Relief and mrMR. The ranking was (1st to 200th) have been acquired from both of these methods. Is it make sense if I combine these two results by averaging (arithmetically or geometrically) to got a set of ranking that represent the both methods?